# Why does distinct work via flatMap, but not via map's "sub-stream"?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm reading in lines of text, and creating a list of its unique words (after lowercasing them). I can make this work with flatMap, but can't make it work with a map's "sub" stream. The flatMap seems more concise and "better", but why does distinct work in one context but not the other?

Class top:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class GetListOfAllWordsInLinesOfText {

   private static final String INPUT = "Line 1\n" +
                              "Line 2, which is a really long line\n" +
                              "A moderately long line 3\n" +
                              "Line 4\n";
   private static final Pattern WORD_SEPARATOR_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\W+");

   public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Why does this distinct allow duplicates through:

```
      final List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
      Arrays.stream(INPUT.split("\n"))
            .forEach(line -> WORD_SEPARATOR_PATTERN.splitAsStream(line).
                        map(String::toLowerCase)
                        distinct().
                        forEach(wordList::add));

      System.out.println("Output via map:");
      wordList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

      System.out.println("--------");
```

Output:

```
Output via map:
line
1
line
2
which
is
a
really
long
a
moderately
long
line
3
line
4
```

But this correctly eliminates duplicates?

```
      final List<String> wordList2 = Arrays.stream(INPUT.split("\n")).flatMap(
            WORD_SEPARATOR_PATTERN::splitAsStream).map(String::toLowerCase).
            distinct()
            .collect(toList());

      System.out.println("Output via flatMap:");
      wordList2.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
line
1
2
which
is
a
really
long
moderately
3
4
```

Here's the full output, including the below `peek`s. You can see the duplicates being correctly filtered by the flatMap version, but not the map version:

map:

```
map before distinct -> line
map after distinct -> line
map before distinct -> 1
map after distinct -> 1
map before distinct -> line
map after distinct -> line
map before distinct -> 2
map after distinct -> 2
map before distinct -> which
map after distinct -> which
map before distinct -> is
map after distinct -> is
map before distinct -> a
map after distinct -> a
map before distinct -> really
map after distinct -> really
map before distinct -> long
map after distinct -> long
map before distinct -> line
map before distinct -> a
map after distinct -> a
map before distinct -> moderately
map after distinct -> moderately
map before distinct -> long
map after distinct -> long
map before distinct -> line
map after distinct -> line
map before distinct -> 3
map after distinct -> 3
map before distinct -> line
map after distinct -> line
map before distinct -> 4
map after distinct -> 4
Output via map:
line
1
line
2
which
is
a
really
long
a
moderately
long
line
3
line
4
--------
```

flatMap:

```
flatMap before distinct -> line
flatMap after distinct -> line
flatMap before distinct -> 1
flatMap after distinct -> 1
flatMap before distinct -> line
flatMap before distinct -> 2
flatMap after distinct -> 2
flatMap before distinct -> which
flatMap after distinct -> which
flatMap before distinct -> is
flatMap after distinct -> is
flatMap before distinct -> a
flatMap after distinct -> a
flatMap before distinct -> really
flatMap after distinct -> really
flatMap before distinct -> long
flatMap after distinct -> long
flatMap before distinct -> line
flatMap before distinct -> a
flatMap before distinct -> moderately
flatMap after distinct -> moderately
flatMap before distinct -> long
flatMap before distinct -> line
flatMap before distinct -> 3
flatMap after distinct -> 3
flatMap before distinct -> line
flatMap before distinct -> 4
flatMap after distinct -> 4
Output via flatMap:
line
1
2
which
is
a
really
long
moderately
3
4
```

Full code:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class GetListOfAllWordsInLinesOfText {

   private static final String INPUT = "Line 1\n" +
                              "Line 2, which is a really long line\n" +
                              "A moderately long line 3\n" +
                              "Line 4\n";
   private static final Pattern WORD_SEPARATOR_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\W+");

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      final List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
      Arrays.stream(INPUT.split("\n"))
            .forEach(line -> WORD_SEPARATOR_PATTERN.splitAsStream(line).map(String::toLowerCase)
                  .peek(word -> System.out.println("map before distinct -> " + word)).
                        distinct().
                        peek(word -> System.out.println("map after distinct -> " + word)).
                        forEach(wordList::add));

      System.out.println("Output via map:");
      wordList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

      System.out.println("--------");

      final List<String> wordList2 = Arrays.stream(INPUT.split("\n")).flatMap(
            WORD_SEPARATOR_PATTERN::splitAsStream).map(String::toLowerCase).
                  peek(word -> System.out.println("flatMap before distinct -> " + word)).
            distinct()
                  .peek(word -> System.out.println("flatMap after distinct -> " + word))
            .collect(toList());

      System.out.println("Output via flatMap:");
      wordList2.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
   }
}
```

Comment: Would a `LinkedHashSet` be of any use to you? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first code snippet uses `forEach` to process each line, and `distinct` within this `forEach` - so the duplicities are eliminated, but only within a line, not globally.

See the output for second line, the repeated occurence of 'line' is actually eliminated since it is repeated on the same line.

Comment: Now that you say it, it's obvious. Don't know what what was stopping me from seeing it before. Thank you.